# Given an expression to be consumed by the "Where" method of an IQueryable, a nested "Any" method will accept a "Func<>" only if it's defined inline

Tags: linq, lambda, iqueryable, func

Keep in mind that the **inner Any method** accepts a **Func<MyChildEntity, bool>** argument, not a **Expression<Func<MyChildEntity, bool>>**.

I think I'm aware of the difference between the 2 (function pointer vs expression tree). But still, the inner Any method accepts a func, not an expression, so..

..this works:

```
var entities = session.Query<MyEntity>()
.Where(m => m.Children.Any(s => s.Prop == "test"))
.ToListAsync();
```

This doesn't:

```
Func<MyEntityChild, bool> childFunc = m => m.Prop == "test";

var entities = session.Query<MyEntity>()
.Where(m => m.Children.Any(childFunc))
.ToListAsync();
```

This doesn't work either:

```
var entities = session.Query<MyEntity>()
.Where(m => m.Children.Any(s => childFunc(s)))
.ToListAsync();
```

At the moment I'm using NHibernate to process the IQueryable, but forget about NHibernate and possible NHibernate bugs..**how is the first (working) example different from the other two (not working) from the point of view of IQueryable consumer?** (as stated, NHibernate in this instance..)

edit: spelling

further edit: corrected comparison from = to ==

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put `Func` and make query work, it should be Expression. To make your query translatable, expression should be preprocessed to make it work. It can be done by [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)

Activate extension:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .WithExpressionExpanding(); // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Then use `Invoke` LINQKit extension:

```cs
Expression<Func<MyEntityChild, bool>> childFunc = m => m.Prop == "test";

var entities = session.Query<MyEntity>()
    .Where(m => m.Children.Any(s => childFunc.Invoke(s)))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I understand your point - infact I expected "any" to require an expression, not a func, but without such kit it actually accepts a Func..and if such func is defined inline it works! How is this possible? What I'd like to understand is how a func defined inline vs a func passed as an argument can be different from the point of view of the IQueryable consumer..

Comment: When defined inline, compiler transfers it to Expression Tree that's why it works. `Func` is compiled lambda method and EF cannot understand what is body of this lambda. LINQKit helps to inject lambda Expression Tree into final query.

Comment: So basically there's an ambiguity in the method signature - which you tell me doesn't correspond to what the compiler does? Are there other examples of this kind of behaviors in C#? It doesn't seem really make sense..is there any info about this in the official reference?

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I could find is that you're missing an `=` in the function:

```
\\ '==' instead of '='
Func<MyEntityChild, bool> childFunc = m => m.Prop == "test";
```

Now this should work:

```
var entities = session.Query<MyEntity>()
.Where(m => m.Children.Any(s => childFunc(s)))
.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: thank you but no of course that's not the problem, I was just writing pseudocode and mistyped the operator. Fixed, thanks for noticing anyway =)