# How to pass a predicate to a "where" method of an included navigation property correctly?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to construct "where" predicate for the included property of the linq query depend on conditions. To reach this I use expressions and in the result I get the predicate with `Func<in T, out TResult>` type. But when I try to pass the predicate to the `.Where()` method of the included property I got the exception:

```
var result = query
    .Include(x => x.Collection.Where(predicate))
    .ToList();
```

Exception:

```
Expression of type 'System.Func`2[...]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[...]]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[...] Where[...](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[...], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[...]])' (Parameter 'arg1')
```

But passing of the lambda that is equivalent to the predicate directly doesn't cause any problems:

```
var result = query
    .Include(x => x.Collection.Where(c => someCondition1(c) && someCondition2(c)))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74079272/10646316) on similar question.  You have to use third party extensions.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv It seems to be solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Linq need to be able to take the predicate expression apart, to create an SQL statement out of it.  Hence, instead of

```
Func<Item, bool> predicate = (c => someCondition1(c) && someCondition2(c);
```

it needs to be:

```
Expression<Func<Item, bool>> predicate = (c => someCondition1(c) && someCondition2(c);
```

Comment: Making it as an expression will not help to inject this predicate into `Include`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in case of `Include` method `Where` must take `Func` predicate, not `Expression`